# illegal continue statement in javascript $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error that this has an illegal continue statement.
I have a list of words to check for form validation and the problem is it was matching some of the substrings to the reserved words so I created another array of clean words to match. If it matches a clean word continue else if it matches a reserved word alert the user

```
$.each(resword,function(){
        $.each(cleanword,function(){
            if ( resword == cleanword ){
                continue;
            }
            else if ( filterName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this) != -1 ) {
                console.log("bad word");
                filterElem.css('border','2px solid red');
                window.alert("You can not include '" + this + "' in your Filter Name");
                fail = true;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The `continue` statement is fine for normal JavaScript loops, but the jQuery `each` method requires you to use the `return` statement instead. Return anything that's not false and it will behave as a `continue`. Return false, and it will behave as a `break`:

```
$.each(cleanword,function(){
    if ( resword == cleanword ){
        return true;
    }
    else if ( filterName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this) != -1 ) {
        //...your code...
    }
});
```

For more information, see the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: Actually, jQuery doesn't check it loosely, if it isn't explicitly false (`=== false`) then it will continue.  So you can just do a `return;` and it will return undefined which will act as a continue.

Comment: @Bob - Thanks, I wasn't 100% sure whether it had to be explicitly false, or just falsy.

Answer (score 10):

Replace the continue with

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using `continue` which is meant for javascript `for` loops inside a jquery `each` handler.  This won't work.  The equivalent of `continue` in jquery `each` though is returning a non-false value.

```
if ( resword == cleanword ){
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery.each loop you have to either return true or false to alter the loop interations:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

So you would need to do this:

```
$.each(resword,function(){
    $.each(cleanword,function(){
        if ( resword == cleanword ){
            return true;
        }
        else if ( filterName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this) != -1 ) {
            console.log("bad word");
            filterElem.css('border','2px solid red');
            window.alert("You can not include '" + this + "' in your Filter Name");
            fail = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in Jquery each method we are calling a function each time we loop inside array, so `continue` will not work, we need to `return true` to get out from a function.
only in simple loops without anonymous function we can use `continue`

Answer (score -1):

You can't use continue there. It will continue automatically anyway, just remove that - and I think it should work per your description.